# Getting maximum value from a group of values and dividing the yearly yield

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable which takes the maximum value from one array and divides by the `year` yield of the same product. For example ,

```
orangesum<- c(12,20,NA,60)
applesum<-   c(4,NA,222,34)
grapesum<- c(4,33,NA,223)
orangeysum<- c(400,220,330,456)
appleysum <-  c(220,340,394,349)
grapeysum<- c(33,344,33,2345)
year<-  c(2008,2009,2010,2011)

df<- data.frame(orangesum,applesum, grapesum, orangeysum, appleysum,grapeysum, year)
```

I want to create a variable called `maxyield` which is the maximum value in the record/maximum value of the yearly yield of that type of product. so in the first row it would be 12/400, 33/344, 222/394,223/2345. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated it! You solution worked wonderful! I am getting NaN for some records, How should i address them?

Comment: In your original dataset, there could be all NA elements for a particular row for the subset dataset.  It is better to leave it as NaN if that is the case.

Comment: @akrun `pmax(NA)` gives `NA`; and `x/NA` or `NA/x` gives `NA`. Maybe their NaNs are from dividing by zero (when that is the max `*ysum`)? Anyway, yeah, if it's from division by zero, best to leave them as NaN.

Comment: I see thats good. I am getting mean as Inf when i have this NaN values.

Comment: I used  ifelse(df1$maxyield=='NaN',0,df1$maxyield) but didn't help

Comment: @user3 Fyi, you'll want to use `is.nan` instead of comparing with `==`. Read `?is.nan` for details.

Comment: @Frank That could be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmax` to get the `max` value of rows for the subset of datasets i.e `df[1:3]` and `df[4:6]` (which corresponds to columns named like `*sum` vs. `*ysum`) and divide those to create the 'maxyield':

```
df$maxyield <- do.call(pmax, c(df[1:3], na.rm=TRUE))/do.call(pmax, c(df[4:6], na.rm = TRUE))
df$maxyield
#[1] 0.03000000 0.09593023 0.56345178 0.09509595
```